# How to export as a vector file with Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I designed a logo, exported as JPG, but it becomes blurry and cluttered when shrunk. I have seen the suggestion that I should export it as as a vector file. So, I exported as AI, but it only opens in Illustrator. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome along. Please can you post a screenshot of it in illustrator, and the bad version? What are you trying to use it for? You should always export an image at the pixel size you intend to use it.

Comment: You might also benefit from searching this site. There are a  number of similar questions ehre which may help. Look to the right of this page.. under the "Related" headline (assuming you are not on a mobile screen)

Comment: You export it as svg not ai if you want to websites to be able to view it. SVG is vector

Comment: @close voters: Yes, this is an extremely basic question, but the asker did research, elaborates what they tried, and it is very clear what they need to know.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I disagree. Typing in the title into Google gave me lots of relevant hits. The top answer even (as I saw too late) makes this an exact duplicate of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/35358/30216

Comment: @usr2564301: Duplicate closure is something else and not what this question was voted to close for so far. Particularly it doesn’t make the question bad. Also keep in mind that I just changed the title to make it more informative.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft the question is impossible answer we can not know what the user is seeing. Also sometimes people interpret  antialiasaing as blur so whi knows what the user is seeing.

Comment: @joojaa: What the asker interprets as blur is irrelevant to this question; it’s just the preface.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft no its not theres 4 separate problems that could be what the askert is asking.

Answer (score 2):

**FWIW**, when exporting as a vector for mobile or general web use, you want to use SVG as the format - this is easily parsed by most modern browsers, and is part of the basic HTML 5 specification, and so is also supported in most other vector graphics applications